# convert shared memory into register with Cuda

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Is there a way to convert the shared memory that I'm not using into register memory? What command should I use when I compile with nvcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the HW resource that provides the shared memory is distinct from the HW resource that provides the register space, and the shared memory HW cannot substitute for registers.

Comment: So if I need more register space couldn't I just use some extra memory from the shared one? No way to do something like that?

Comment: No, there isn't.  If you're not using shared memory at all, or very little of it, you can tell the GPU that and it will allow some shared memory to be used as L1.  This is covered [in the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#architecture-2-x).  But this doesn't impact register usage, and newer CUDA runtime packages should detect this condition automatically, and shift the shared memory split to prefer L1.  There is no way to repurpose the shared memory as register space.